# Proper System Exit codes

Tags: linux, exit-code

*A quick explanation and summary:*

In HTTP, there are expected codes to represent certain things. For example, `200` means everything is good, whereas `500` means the server is having a problem. 
Native applications also return status codes. For example, git returns a `0` when everything is ok, but returns a `128` if git isnt set up in the current directory. (Bash returns `127` if git isnt even installed)

*Now, the question:*

**When creating my own application, is there any standard convention that should be used for exit codes?**

I know that I should return `0` for when the program exits properly. Is there a standard such as the http standard for exit codes?

Answer (score 0):

`EXIT_SUCCESS` (i.e. 0) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (1) are standard, in `<stdlib.h>`). Read also [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) and [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) man pages. Notice that the argument of `exit` function is bit-or-ed with `0377` octal.

Some BSD systems have more conventions (perhaps in a `<sysexits.h>` header, see [sysexits](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=sysexits) man page), but GNU/Linux does not follow them a lot.

I suggest sticking to `EXIT_FAILURE` -on failure- but giving, if possible or relevant, an error message (to `stderr` or thru [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) ...)

Some commands document their few exit codes.